# Possible bug is Jenkins Swarm plugin - fsroot to set Remote root directory relative vs full path

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have latest Jenkins and it's Swarm plugin client jar (2.0).

I downloaded the swarm-client jar and I ran the following command to create the slave: (**Note:** : I'm using user *Anonymous* to connect to Jenkins master without requiring username/password and have provided Create Slave permission in Global Roles, and all access in Slave section under Slave roles by creating a new role with pattern **swarm.***). Jenkins Swarm client: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Swarm+Plugin

*A user can provide a valid username/password if that user has Create Slave (Global Roles) and other access like connect, delete, etc in Slave Roles in Jenkins under Manage Roles*).

```
$ which swarm-client.jar
~/tools/bin/swarm-client.jar
$ pwd
/home/confman/slaves
$ ~/tools/jdk1.7.0_60/bin/java -jar `which swarm-client.jar` -name "swarm_`hostname -a`" -fsroot "~/slaves/swarm_`hostname -a`" -master  http://jenkins_master.srvr.company.com:8083 -username Anonymous -description "`hostname -a` " -executors 5 -labels "ANSIBLE_CENTOS CENTOS" -mode 'exclusive'  -showHostName -t java=~/tools/jdk1.8.0_45 -t gradle=~/tools/gradle-2.3 -t Maven=~/tools/apache-maven-3.3.3 -t Groovy2=~/tools/groovy-2.4.5 --showHostName -retry 0 -disableClientsUniqueId &
```

But, instead of the above command setting Slave's **Remote Root Directory** to **~/slaves/swarm_jmeter01**, it's setting the remote root path including the folder as prefix/relative to from where I ran the above command (as shown below). **In my case**, *hostname* command value is *jmeter01*.

[image]

The documentation doesn't mention that this paramter is relative to the current folder (where you'd run the java -jar slave-client jar  command).

Has anyone found a solution for this i.e. it can ignore the current folder and set it to ~/slaves/swarm_01 or something like that?

Obviously In my automation to resolve this issue, I can first "cd" (change directory) to the correct folder ~/slaves and then just pass -fsroot "swarm_`hostname -a`" to get remote directory path value set as: ~/slaves/swarm_jmeter01 (in that case, it'll work fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

~ is shell expansion ... if this not works, then use $HOME instead

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem

Comment: @Odedra yep, that's what I did but without the ", " doube quotes. The issue was with the double quotes.

Comment: $HOME is an environment variable supported by all shells and all places in scripts/parameters... 
The tilde must not be supported everywhere (in the "older times"^^). 

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/tilde
writes:
> Tilde expansion is only performed, when the tilde-construct 
> is at the beginning of a word, or a separate word.
(which is not the case in quoting)

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesnt-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes
also had some equal anser for it.